# Ubuntu Base update fails

Tags: grub2, dpkg

Since the last attempt to upgrade *grub-pc* and *grub-efi-amd64-signed*
as part of a base update, the update fails to complete. Here's the output:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    2 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.12) ...
    dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
    installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
     grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
      Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
      Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
==========
```

I've attempted to install grub-efi-amd64 manually but that fails too.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu?  and if so what release?  (package details tell us what it looks like, but do we need to guess?).  Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` (an attempt to have it fixed automatically?) though I suspect it's related to your sources (or an outdated mirror).  Can you please tell us your release of Ubuntu, and provide `apt-cache query grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc`  (edit your question and please add additional information there)

Comment: Updating the issue: I was able to get it corrected but it was a bit painful. APT and DPKG could not fix it, nor could Boot-Repair. I finally manually deleted every instance of grub-efi-amd64-* and grub-efi in the system directories. APT was then able to re-install GRUB2, and Boot-Repair did its thing.

I know others have had this issue as well. Apparently it can be fixed with APT in most cases. For my case it did not.